# Is this a Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have written a code below is the code

```
public class StaticDeadlock
{
    private static final Object o = new Object();

    static {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();

        try {
            thread.join(); 
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("all is well.");
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            System.out.println("inside mythread");
            o.getClass();
        }
    }

}
```

I am calling `thread.join()` in the **static** block which make my main thread to wait till my thread declared in static block to complete and this thread is calling `o.getClass();` where "o" is the instance of the `static final Object o = new Object();` when running the code my Main thread and my static block thread gets dead lock. I want to confirm is this really a dead lock or some other issue. The output below upon execution of the program.

output:

```
inside mythread
```

not completing the program. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @G.S definitely a dup. The code looks identical.